# Loading NRRD file in Javascript using XTK

Tags: xtk

My question is if it is possible to load a NRRD file in JavaScript using XTK library. When I tried to use X.loader() I get an error that it does not exist. I would like to just load a file not render it. I have read that there could be a specialized XTK IO library, but the library I found (XIO) does not supports NRRD file format. 
  Also, does anyone know why JetBrains Webstorm does not support auto-complete for XTK? Is there a way to enable that support?
  Thank you.

Best regards,

LoneWolf

Comment: have you tried http://lessons.goxtk.com/10/ ?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But the issue is that I need XTK only to load NRRD file, I must write my own renderer. I have tried to use an answer from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16950718/load-volume-in-xtk-without-initializing-a-renderer but I get a message that X.loader is not a function. What am I missing? Is it possible to compile XTK library so that I will get only the part I need.